# Custom clone of unique_ptr doesn't return correct type

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have these 2 classes:

```cpp
class Operation {
    public:
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Operation> clone() = 0;
};

class Plus : public Operation {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<Operation> clone() override {
            return std::make_unique<Plus>(*this);
        };
};
```

I have this function, that checks the type of a functtion:

```cpp
template<typename Base, typename T>
inline bool instanceof(const T*) {
   return std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value;
}
```

I have encountered problems with my clone method, it doesn't pass my instanceof, after I cloned the object.

```
std::unique_ptr<SweCpp::Upn::classesforOp::Plus> p1 = std::make_unique<SweCpp::Upn::classesforOp::Plus>();
auto p2 = p1->clone();

if(!instanceof<SweCpp::Upn::classesforOp::Plus>(p2.get())) return false;
return true;
```

This check fails, since I return the general type of `unique_ptr<Operation>` and not `unique_ptr<Plus>` in my clone method. How can I change my clone, so it returns the child class, and not my interface class `Operation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template parameters are backwards.  You are setting `Base` to `Plus`, and `T` is deduced as `Operation`.  You are thus calling `std::is_base_of<Plus, Operation>::value` which is always false since `Plus` is not a base of `Operation`.  The opposite is true, `Operation` is a base of `Plus`.  So swap the template parameters around:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Base>
inline bool instanceof(const Base*) {
   return std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value;
}
```

Now, with that said, this `instanceof()` is still not doing the correct thing to begin with. `std::is_base_of` is a *compile-time* check, but you can't check polymorphic object types at *compile-time*, since the compiler doesn't know what derived type a base pointer will actually be pointing at. It only knows the type of the pointer itself.

Let's say you define another class other then `Plus` that also derives from `Operation`, and then you pass a clone of that other class to your version of `instanceof()`, then `std::is_base_of<Operation, Plus>::value` will still be true even though the object is not actually an instance of `Plus`.

To solve this, you need to use `dynamic_cast` to check the object type at *runtime* instead, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Base>
inline bool instanceof(const Base *b) {
   return dynamic_cast<const T*>(b) != nullptr;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/kuC9H7)

Comment: That solved the problem on the spot, thank you very much <3